# Django. Прочитать параметр, переданный через url

Tags: python-3.x, django

Текст view.py:

```
def main(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'main.html', {})
    else:
        return redirect('accounts/login/?next=/welcome')

def login(request):
    print(request.next)
    return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Текст urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='main.html'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login')
]
```

Как в login получить значение параметра next?

Шаблон с отправкой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500859/django-request-get

Comment: Нам бы еще кусок шаблона где идет отправка запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переадресовываясь на страницу `accounts/login/?next=/welcome` вы передёте стандартный GET запрос(его параметры кодируются через адрес). Чтобы получить этот параметр попробуйте вместо `request.next` использовать `request.GET["next"]`. `request.GET` -- словарь, который хранит все пары ключ-значение, которые вы ему передали.

---

А если вы посылаете POST запрос, то соответственно выцепляйте из `request.POST`